# how can I filter data inside mutate() using a counting function (like NROW) in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with the columns `doc_id` and `feats` (both character vectors). I'm trying to create a new column `n_rel_prn`, which has the number of total occurrences of the value `'PronType=Rel'` in the `feats` column, for each `doc_id`.

I can't use filter(), because it filters out all of the other data I need (i.e. where the value for `feats` is not `'PronType=Rel'`), but otherwise it does the trick. (Here's that code snippet:)

```
tcorpus %>% group_by(doc_id) %>%
  filter(feats=='PronType=Rel') %>%
  mutate(n_rel_prn = n())
```

Basically, I need something that works like the following code (except that actually works--this obviously doesn't):

```
tcorpus %>% group_by(doc_id) %>%
  mutate(n_rel_prn = NROW(feats == 'PronType=Rel'))
```

Is there a way I can count the number of `'PronType=Rel'` observations (grouped by doc_id) and add these totals to a new column? (I'm assuming at the very least `group_by %>% mutate()` is the way to go.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. Try this:

```
tcorpus %>% group_by(doc_id) %>% mutate(n_rel_prn = sum(feats == 'PronType=Rel'))
```

Comment: unfortunately this didn't work, it just filled the new n_rel_prn column with NAs.

Comment: oh, then how about `tcorpus %>% group_by(doc_id) %>% mutate(n_rel_prn = sum(feats == 'PronType=Rel', na.rm = TRUE))`? If this one still doesn't work, please consider providing a reproducible example using `dput(tcorpus)`.

Comment: I converted the NAs to zeros and the first one worked. Thanks!

Comment: `na.rm = TRUE` is a much safer approach. I'd be careful there.